# Learning Unix and C — viewing the process, file and v-node tables

Tags: c, linux, unix, file-io, process

I'm currently reading about process tables, file tables and v-node tables in the book [*Advanced Programming in the Unix Environment*](http://www.apuebook.com/).

To aid my understanding, it would be useful to be able to view the process table, file table and v-node tables and the relationships between them.  How can I view these internal structures when I am writing and debugging c code?

I have tried to piece the internal structure information together using the output from `ps` and `ls` and sketching the relationships on paper to visualise the structures, but that is quite slow going.

There seems to be a lot of posts on the internet about viewing the process table, but not viewing the process table, file table and v-node tables and their relationships.

Comment: Don't [delete and re-post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18757244/learning-unix-and-c-viewing-the-process-file-and-v-node-tables) (10k) to "erase" close votes. Deleting your own posts is bad for your account's health. Continuing previous comments, now you're failing the "what have you tried"/"what research did you do on this and what didn't you understand in what you found" tests. Searching for "linux c process table" gives a few hints, including here on SO.

Comment: Ah, thanks Mat.  I thought that because I changed the question a fair bit, the original comments no longer applied. I wasn't trying to remove the close votes.

Comment: "... sketching the relationships on paper ..." Really? I though you wanted to code? What _code_ have you tried? What source did you read? This is a site for _specific_ programming questions.

Comment: I was sketching the relationships in the internal structures to help 'understand' what was happening under the hood.  See [trojanfoe's](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18758682/1033422) answer as he has hit the nail on the head.

Comment: I understand what you did. My comment was to tell you your question still falls short of the Stack Overflow "what have you tried" rules. And repeating the advice in the post you deleted: searching for "linux C process table" would have gotten you that advice already, on this site. Jonathan's advice you deleted with your previous post was also good and would have lead you to the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think most of what you are asking is exposed by the `procfs` virtual filesystem, mounted as `/proc`.

The top-level `/proc` directory contains the process ID of every running process, presented as a directory.

Within each *process directory* are files and sub-directories containing information for the process, and one sub-directory is `/proc/XXX/fd/`, which contains the files opened by the process.

Please see the following documentation for more information:

http://www.tldp.org/LDP/Linux-Filesystem-Hierarchy/html/proc.html
http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/11/linux-proc-file-system/

or anything else shown when you Google "linux /proc filesystem".